# Importing JAR (JAudioTagger) in Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, jar

I'm working on a program which loads the song data of a mp3 file. Im trying to import JAudioTagger to help load the song information. The JAudioTagger is a .jar file. I went into the import window but was faced with many import options which I am not sure about. It looks like there are three options which would work; EJB JAR file, Java EE Utility Jar, or App Client JAR file. I'm not sure if any of these options are the correct ones.

Does anyone know about how to import the jar? I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Thanks in advance.

[JAudioTagger Site](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/index.jsp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Right click** on your project.
2. Select **Build Path**.
3. Select **Add External Archives**.
4. Select the jar-file.
5. You can now use the classes from your library.

Comment: For the new version of adt you just drop the jar in the libs folder, notice it should be the .jar not the source.jar or the javadoc.jar ;) (yes I wasted hours)

Comment: Did you get it to work? According to this open bug report, and my experience trying to import the library, it doesn't seem to be supported on Android. https://java.net/jira/browse/JAUDIOTAGGER-303

Comment: This lib doesn't support Android